# get path city table in yii or php

Tags: php, mysql, select, yii, tree

**city table**

```
id           name          parent_id
-------------------------------------
1            tehran        0
2            tehranpars    1
3            afsariye      1
4            jashnvare     2
5            semnan        0
6            shahroud      5
```

i want get only path "jashnvare"

i have only id "jashnvare"

i want one query for select this output in yii or php , Preference yii

**output**:

tehran,tehranpars,jashnvare

thank you

Comment: Thats great. Do you have a question? Have you attempted code? Also, since you have to recursive up the tree 2 levels it is highly unlikely that you will be able to do it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

In CDbCriteria, you can use `select` attribute and assign "jashnvare" to it.
More details on [Yii CDbCriteria select](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#select-detail)

Comment: i want get path jashnvare by parent_id, output: "tehran,tehranpars,jashnvare"